# withSessionContinueSeconds method doesn't work in Flurry

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, flurry, flurry-analytics

I have the following code:

```
let builder = FlurrySessionBuilder.init()
                                              .withAppVersion(appVersion)
                                              .withLogLevel(FlurryLogLevelAll)
                                              .withCrashReporting(true)
                                              .withSessionContinueSeconds(20)
```

I wanted to increase the number od seconds before the session times out because of the nature of the app I am writing. However, the session timeout is still after 10 seconds rather than the 20 I have specified in my code.

How can I fix this?

Comment: How do you know it's still 10 seconds?

Comment: Because in the Flurry dashboard a new session starts after 10 seconds when reopening the app but not if the app is reopened before 10 seconds has passed since closing the app, a new session isn't started.

Comment: Look like a bug in Flurry SDK. Your best bet is to file it here https://github.com/flurry/flurry-ios-sdk/issues